# Simple create - lseek - read program in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to create a simple program which creates a file, writes on it, then moves back the pointer and finally reads it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){ 

  int fd = creat("/home/alum/Class/ej",S_IRWXU);
  if(fd==-1){
    printf("Error %d\n",errno);
    return 1;
  }

  ssize_t size = write(fd, "Halo",4);
  if(size==-1){
    printf("Error %d\n",errno);
    return 1;
  }

  char string[50];
  lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);  
  while((size = read(fd, string, 49)) >0){    
    printf("Read[%d]: %s\n",size,string);
  }

  printf("Size: %d\n",size);

  if(size==-1){
    printf("Error %d\n",errno);
    return 1;
  }

  int c=close(fd);
  if(c==-1){
    printf("Error %d\n",errno);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that "lseek" seems not to be working. I always get size "-1" when I try to read, so I assume I'm not going back to the beginning of the file... Any suggestions?

I've seen some questions related to lseek but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

EDIT:

I changed

```
  int fd = creat("/home/alum/Class/ej",S_IRWXU);
```

to

```
  int fd = open("/home/alum/Class/ej",O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
```

and also tried

```
  int fd = open("/home/alum/Class/ej",O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,0700);
```

As suggested but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: According to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat), "creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC", so it seems you can't read from a file opened with `creat` (flag `O_WRONLY`)

Comment: I tried using open and I get the same error (changes in the post)

Comment: Fixed it using O_RDWR, Thanks!

Comment: use `perror` instead of `printf`. It will print a human-readable error message.

Comment: Note: `string` is not a _string_ when `printf("Read[%d]: %s\n",size,string)` is called as `string` lacks a certain _null character_.  (UB)

Comment: @chux yes thanks! I end up adding '/0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use

```
int fd = open("/home/alum/Class/ej",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0700);
```

to create the file since 'creat' does not work for reading ([manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat)) and 'open' didn't work as O_RDWR for me if I used O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY.

Comment: *I used O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY.*  And it is completely [**wrong** to do that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):  "Applications shall specify **exactly one** of the first five values (file access modes) below in the value of oflag:  O_EXEC
...
O_RDONLY
...
O_RDWR
...
O_SEARCH
...
O_WRONLY"